# How do I batch-downsize images on linux, while keeping small images small?

Tags: linux, images, batch, mogrify

I have a whole lot of photos and it's time to clean up the mess and free some disk space.
I know mogrify is great to batch-resize things down. The problem is, in some directories I have small images mixed with the big ones. I'd like to batch-downsize all the big one but not upsize the small ones.

As an example, I have a rep with tens of MBs-pictures in the 3000x2000s. Some of them I have already downsized so I could email them. They may be 1024x768. I'd like to downsize the big ones to 1600x1200, a disk-space-to-quality tradeoff I like. But then, with `mogrify` or `convert`, the small ones will be upsized, which would be a waste of disk space.

I found some tricky ways to use `identify` with `cut` and some scripting to filter the small pics out and mogrify the others, but man, there's got to be a way to tell mogrify not to upsize my pics... How ?

Is there some other tool better suited ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `convert`, you can specify the parameter `>` to only shrink bigger images, leaving the other untouched (the \ is required, or the magic char > is not escaped):

```
convert large_image.png -resize 1248x1024\> large_image.png
convert not_large_image.png -resize 1248x1024\> not_large_image.png
```

It will only change the bigger images.

[ETA] `convert` is [part of ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php).

Comment: Works with `mogrify`, too !